# Jquery adjusting datepicker , day information

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to set more information in each day instead of just the day.

I'm directly editing the datepicker file.This is around line 1556.

The old code.

```
(otherMonth ? ' ui-priority-secondary' : '') + // distinguish dates from other months
                            '" href="#">' + printDate.getDate() + '</a>')) + '</td>';
```

The edited code .

```
(otherMonth ? ' ui-priority-secondary' : '') + // distinguish dates from other months
                            '" href="#"><div class="dinfo"><div class="'+urdayn+'">' + printDate.getDate() + '</div><div class="udayt">test</div></div></a>')) + '</td>';
```

P.S urdayn is just a name of class.

SO first code is the default code, and the calendar works with it, but the second code, it's not working properly.Everything is ok, changing months showing dates how i want them to show, but if i click on a day, and try to get to other month after i've clicked, the calendar hides, and the buttons - prev,next and the center header are showing undefined NaN.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the onClick event of the link. So if it's works for you; you can add div out of link tags. Like that:

```
<div class="dinfo"><div class="'+urdayn+'"><a class="ui-state-default'
...
printDate.getDate() + '</a></div>'
```

Comment: I had to change some code to make the look wright, but that was it, thnx.